# Looping backwards with condition

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to make a time series in pandas, which says if day of the month is equal to 27 then give my column a value of 1. However if that day of the week of the date is on a weekend put the 1 on the friday before.

I've done the first bit;

```
df_pay=datelist.copy()
df_pay['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df_pay['Date'])

df_pay['Day']=df_pay['Date'].dt.day
df_pay['PayDay_27']=float(0)
df_pay['DoW'] = df_pay['Date'].dt.weekday_name

df_pay.loc[(df_pay['Day']==27) & ~(df_pay['DoW'].str.contains('|'.join(['Saturday','Sunday']))),'PayDay_27'] = 1
```

And think I need a backwards loop for the second bit, but can't put them together

```
for i, row in enumerate(df_pay[::-1].iterrows()):
    if df_pay.loc[df_pay.index==i,'Day']==25 & df_pay.loc[df_pay.index==i,'DoW']=='Saturday'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Add conditionals for Saturday and Sunday.

```
df_pay=datelist.copy()
df_pay['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df_pay['Date'])

df_pay['Day']=df_pay['Date'].dt.day
df_pay['PayDay_27']=float(0)
df_pay['DoW'] = df_pay['Date'].dt.weekday_name 

list_indx = df_pay.index[df_pay["Day"]==27].tolist()  

for indx in list_indx:
    if df_pay.at[indx ,"Dow"] == "Saturday" and idx>0:
        df_pay.at[indx -1,"PayDay_27"] = 1
    elif df_pay.at[indx ,"Dow"] == "Sunday" and idx>1:
        df_pay.at[indx -2,"PayDay_27"] = 1
    else:
        df_pay.at[indx ,"PayDay_27"] = 1
```

Comment: Arent' you missing a `for` loop on `indx_1`?

Comment: Yes, i miss it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
#27 is not on weekend
mask1 = (df_pay['Date'].dt.day.shift(0) == 27) & df_pay['Date'].dt.weekday.map(lambda x: (x != 5) & (x != 6))
#27 is on saturday
mask2 = (df_pay['Date'].dt.day.shift(1) == 27) & df_pay['Date'].dt.weekday.map(lambda x: x == 4)
#27 is on sunday
mask3 = (df_pay['Date'].dt.day.shift(2) == 27) & df_pay['Date'].dt.weekday.map(lambda x: x == 4)

mask = mask1 | mask2 | mask3

print(df_pay[mask])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following conditions.

```
cond_1 = (df['Date'].dt.day == 27) & (~df['Date'].dt.dayofweek.isin([5, 6]))
cond_2 = ((df['Date'].dt.day == 27) & (df['Date'].dt.dayofweek == 5)).shift(-1)
cond_3 = ((df['Date'].dt.day == 27) & (df['Date'].dt.dayofweek == 6)).shift(-2)

df[cond_1 | cond_2 | cond_3]
```

---

For example, for the DataFrame.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start="2018-01-01", end="2019-01-01"), columns=['Date'])
```

Applying these conditions yields

```
>>> result = df.copy()[cond_1 | cond_2 | cond_3]
>>> result['day_of_week'] = result['Date'].dt.weekday_name
>>> result

    Date        day_of_week
25  2018-01-26  Friday
57  2018-02-27  Tuesday
85  2018-03-27  Tuesday
116 2018-04-27  Friday
144 2018-05-25  Friday
177 2018-06-27  Wednesday
207 2018-07-27  Friday
238 2018-08-27  Monday
269 2018-09-27  Thursday
298 2018-10-26  Friday
330 2018-11-27  Tuesday
360 2018-12-27  Thursday
```